# how to put True type font file in assets folder in android studio

Tags: android, fonts, assets, truetype

I have a True type Fonts file which contains fonts of Rockwell.I need to put it in assets folder in android studio.But i am not able to put it.Can anyone tell how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create `assets` directory under your `main` directory of your project (src/main/assets). copy and paste it in that folder and use it.
these links maybe useful for complete information : [gradle based projects](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

[image: pic]

Comment: i tried to do the same thing u said.But the issue i am facing is that when i copy paste this true_type_font file..theres an error saying its a read only file and refactoring is not possible.

Comment: @user3626890 maybe your file is incorrupted. made a new .ttf file.

Comment: So how do I reference the font name from .ttf file in `fonts.xml`?