# Custom font button not working Android-Studio

Tags: java, android, button, fonts, android-studio

Hello I'm trying to use a Custom font to my Button I've added the font on res/assets.

On my .java I have this code

```
      Button btjoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btJoc);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Heart Breaking Bad.ttf");
    btjoc.setTypeface(font);
    Button bttaula = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btTaula);
    bttaula.setTypeface(font);
```

And it doesn't work... I don't know if I have to put something else, wish you can help me...

Thanks.

Comment: I tried `Heart_Breaking_Bad.ttf` and it doesn't work... I don't see any errors.. I can launch my App without issues..

Comment: You may wish to try renaming the font file to not have spaces in the filename, and see if that helps. You might also try a different font file, as Android does not like all font files.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any logcat error? Do you have related font in your assets directory? try to change your font name in asset folder and your code to `Heart_Breaking_Bad.ttf`

you must moved it to `main/assets` instead of `res/assets`. 
and see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959290/how-to-put-true-type-font-file-in-assets-folder-in-android-studio/25959305#25959305) , maybe help you.

Comment: I tried to move the folder and it still now working... I've put "_"   instead of " " and it still not working too...

Comment: Try another font and post result here.