# Where do I have to put my txt file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, text

I'm trying to read a File from txt, but it's throwing a FileNotFoundException

I already put it in the assets folder, and in the app folder but the exception is still there

Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
var asd=readFileAsLinesUsingReadLines("goodstops.txt")

fun readFileAsLinesUsingReadLines(fileName: String): List<String>
            = File(fileName).readLines()
```

Comment: Adding a path to the file-name might drastically improve the outcome.

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779607/reading-a-txt-file-and-outputing-as-a-textview-in-android/33779896#33779896)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I already put it in the assets folder

Use `getAssets()` on a `Context` to get an `AssetManager`. Call `open("goodstops.txt")` on the `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` to use for reading in the contents of the asset.

Comment: If it's working you should mark the answer as accepted, so other people can get help from it too. @TheDuck

Answer (score 1):

I use extension for AssetManager

```
fun AssetManager.readFile(fileName: String) = open(fileName)
  .bufferedReader()
  .use { it.readText() }
```

to read file:

```
val fileContent = context.assets.readFile("goodstops.txt")
```

Answer (score -1):

Place it in res/raw. 
Right click on res -> new -> Android Resource Directory -> Resource Type: raw

Comment: Hey Stefan, thank you for helping! There are some links that I think could make your answers even more helpful: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/532461), and don't forget the "Answering Questions" section in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)