# Where to store .json file in Android Studio project so i could read it with FileReader?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, libgdx, filereader

I've created an app on Android Studio with Libgdx that can read a .json file that is stored in the project folder

it goes like this

```
 private void readFile() {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("file.json"))
    {
        //reads file
    } catch (IOException | ParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everything works on the desktop application, but when I run it on android app ofcourse its not there and it doesn't load. I can't find any information to where it has to be stored. FileReader only lets me input a string, but not the location where the file is.

Is FileReader a bad choice or the location where it is looking can be changed?

Comment: "Is FileReader a bad choice" -- yes, unless you will be downloading the JSON from a Web server and storing it as a file (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`). For packaging JSON in an app, I recommend placing it in `assets/`, as a peer directory of `src/` and `res/`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522115/115145

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store you json file in assets folder. And to read your .json from assets file use below code.

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(readJSONFromAsset());

public String readJSONFromAsset() {
String json = null;
try {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("yourFile.json");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return json;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've done something like this, but i loaded the file with FileHandle and passed the string to JsonParser. Anyway, great answer. Took me a while to work this out